# Is it possible to get an attachment of Google Calendar event using Calendar Provider?

Tags: android, calendar, google-api, google-calendar-api

It is possible to work with event attachments via [Google Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/create-events#attachments). In case of production calendar apps with synchronization, it is recommended to use [Calendar Provider](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html). However, I was not able to find how to work with event attachments using Calendar Provider. [Events table](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CalendarContract.Events.html) does not seem to have any fields for this.

Can anyone please clarify if it's possible and share any workarounds if it's not?

Comment: This is currently not possible AFAIK.

Comment: So the recommended approach is to use Calendar Provider for syncing all event data (except attachments) and separately use Google Calendar API for syncing attachments - is that correct?